# How can I introduce base class member to derived class definition, but only one overload?

Tags: c++, derived-class, using-declaration

With 'using declarations' I can introduce a base class member into definition of my class:

```
class Base {
    public:
    void baseMemberFn();
    /* ... */
};

class Derived : private Base {
    public:
    using Base::baseMemberFn;
};
```

However, in my case, I want to only 'use' one specific overload of the member from the base class.
Is there a syntax to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no syntax for that.

Make a new member function with the same name, that forwards the call to the parent:

```
void baseMemberFn() {Base::baseMemberFn();}
```